# prevent d3 donut chart from sorting automatically

Tags: d3.js, donut-chart

Is there a way to prevent a donut chart from sorting values automatically? I don't see anywhere where I have specified that values should be sorted, yet, they are arranged in a descending order in clockwise fashion. Any suggestions would be great.

http://jsbin.com/cufuhukuki/edit?js,output

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `sort(null)` in your pie layout:

```
donut = d3.layout.pie().sort(null);
```

Here is your JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/xoqapibuvo/1/edit

Comment: great thank you! I would have imagined that it would not be sorted by default. Is there a good reason to do that out of the box?

Comment: I don't know the reason for this choice, but it's on the API: "The sort order defaults to descending value".